# cannot read and process a very large csv file with nestjs/nodejs

Tags: node.js, io, nestjs, large-data

I am trying to read a very large CSV file with my Nest API, the file has 30000001 rows and has four columns timestamp(*Number*), transaction_type(*string*), token (*string*), amount(*number*).
Now I used node's built-in fs module to read the file with the stream, process every high watermark chunk of the stream, and return the processed response. I have tried to make it work with the help of the following packages but so far the end result is that it fails by the process running out of memory. I tried using the following packages:

- [Line by line](https://www.npmjs.com/package/event-stream.)
- [Nest-Csv-Parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nest-csv-parser)
- [Event Stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/event-stream)

The only way I have been able to gain some results was with the following:

```
    import {
  Injectable,
  BadRequestException,
  NotFoundException,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as path from 'path';
import { Transactions } from 'src/entities/transaction.entity';
const dirPath = path.join(__dirname, '../../src/assets/transactions.csv');
@Injectable()
export class ReadService {
  constructor() {}
  async read(): Promise<any> {
    const readStream = fs.createReadStream(dirPath);
    function streamReader(stream: fs.ReadStream) {
      return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
        const transactions: Transactions[] = [];
        stream.on('data', (chunk) => {
          const line = chunk.toString();
          const [timestamp, transactionType, token, amount] = line.split(',');
          transactions.push({
            timestamp: Number(timestamp),
            transactionType: transactionType,
            token: token,
            amount: Number(amount),
          });
        });
        stream.on('end', () => {
          resolve(transactions);
        });
        stream.on('error', (err) => {
          reject(err);
        });
      });
    }
    return await streamReader(readStream);
  }
}
```

With that I get the following response:

```
[
    {
        "timestamp": null,
        "transactionType": "transaction_type",
        "token": "token",
        "amount": null
    },
    {
        "timestamp": 71869093,
        "transactionType": "WITHDRAWAL",
        "token": "BTC",
        "amount": null
    },
    {
        "timestamp": 92,
        "transactionType": "DEPOSIT",
        "token": "ETH",
        "amount": null
    },
    {
        "timestamp": null,
        "transactionType": "DEPOSIT",
        "token": "ETH",
        "amount": null
    },
    {
        "timestamp": null,
        "transactionType": "BTC",
        "token": "0.275225\n1571574219",
        "amount": null
    },
    {
        "timestamp": 714,
        "transactionType": "DEPOSIT",
        "token": "BTC",
        "amount": null
    },
    {
        "timestamp": null,
        "transactionType": "WITHDRAWAL",
        "token": "BTC",
        "amount": null
    },
......]
```

But the data is not processed as its supposed to be, if I change the processing of the chunks of the above snippet like this:

```
stream.on('data', (chunk: { toString: () => any; }) => {
          const line = chunk.toString();
          const lines = line.split('\n');
          lines.forEach((l: string) => {
            const transaction = l.split(',');
            if (transaction.length === 4) {
              transactions.push({
                timestamp: Number(transaction[0]),
                transactionType: transaction[1],
                token: transaction[2],
                amount: Number(transaction[3]),
              });
            }
          })
        });
```

It crashes because of a lack of memory.

The error message in all and every case:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->
51[22578:0x4dddc00]    70488 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 2048.1 (2081.7) -> 2047.2 (2082.0) MB, 3025.4 / 0.0 ms  (+ 73.0 ms in 18 steps since start of marking, biggest step 5.5 ms, walltime since start of marking 3110 ms) (average mu = 0.226, current mu = 0.162[22578:0x4dddc00]    75233 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 2047.7 (2082.0) -> 2047.5 (2082.2) MB, 4180.4 / 0.0 ms  (+ 21.3 ms in 5 steps since start of marking, biggest step 5.3 ms, walltime since start of marking 4211 ms) (average mu = 0.166, current mu = 0.115)

<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

My queries are:

1. Should I run a worker thread for the processing of the chunks or run clusters?
2. What is the most efficient way for such I/O operation?

Comment: Try it out without that `.push(...)` statement. Does it still crashes?

Comment: No it doesnt crash, I tried to coppy the contents with a spread operator but it took 1 and half hours and still counting so no luck so far. Without returing the processed data the whole function is redundant

Comment: then that's why. I guess you should stream parsed data instead of loading everyting into memory and replying to the client. There are several 3rd-party packages to help you on that

Comment: I'm sorry i am not sure what you are suggesting, should I parse the data and stream write it into another file? or like should I chain up streams (IDK if that's doable yet) ?

Comment: I meant, stream write it to the client. I guess you can use the [`StreamableFile`](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/streaming-files#streamable-file-class) class

Comment: the thing is that you shouldn't be loading every data into memory prior replying the request. Otherwise you'll reach nodejs out of memory issues